# How do I import a text file in sveltekit?

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

I am trying to import a txt file and print the lines in my sveltekit app. I tried to fetch it with the server and also I tried to import it straight into the component but I cannot get either to work. I have tried adding the txt file to both the static folder and public. This is how I tried to import it on the component.

```
onMount(() => {
        loadItems();
    });

    const loadItems = async () => {
        const response = await fetch('public/safety.txt');
        const text = await response.text();
        items = text.split('\n\n'); // split on double newlines
    };

    let currentIndex = 0;

    const interval = setInterval(() => {
        currentIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * items.length);
    }, 5000);

    $: currentItem = items[currentIndex];

    onDestroy(() => {
        clearInterval(interval);
    });
```

And this is how I tried on the server:

```
const safety = await fetch('/public/safety.txt')
```

Comment: Use vite: https://vitejs.dev/guide/assets.html#importing-asset-as-string

Answer (score 2):

You need to put you **static** files under "static" folder. 
For example:

> *yourapp/static/safety.txt*

Then it will be:

```
const response = await fetch('safety.txt');
```

That's it

Mine public json data is dummy.json
[image: Mine public json data is dummy.json]

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear what the error is, but here is a working sample repl: https://svelte.dev/repl/650551a080e84d8da8b37a96bf79a089?version=3.58.0

Comment: I am trying import a text file like the repl, only instead of importing the txt file from a website I have the text file. I am unsure what folder to put the text file in and how to reference it.

Comment: in sveltekit, you can add the file into the public directory and then fetch ('safety.txt'); (exclude the '/static/')

or just try browsing to http://localhost:5173/safety.txt

Comment: I was able to get it working by adding the static folder to the server allow as shown [here](https://vitejs.dev/config/server-options.html#server-fs-allow).